# .addClass not working on jqLite / Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jqlite

I've been struggling lately to understand why the .addClass function was not working on jqLite

```
element.addClass('active')
```

Element returns me an array of html elements, tested that over and over to be sure. I can hide(), show() , add a .css or get one, or even set .attr , but addClass resists me.

edit: element is a path  in a svg block , and this is the reason that seems to make the addClass function irrelevant, still trying to fix it.

element is a jqLite object

Thank you.

Comment: I guess adding class is based on some logic in controller, why not use ngClass?

Comment: I'm doing it into the .mouseenter() function, which is working fine, but .addClass was not working into it, then i tested it into the chrome console, everything is working except the addClass function ...

Comment: _Element returns me an array of html elements_.....would you post the array too in your question.

Comment: There is missing code in this question. element in angular could be used with angular.element method or by directive reference

Comment: Ok so i found the origin of the problem, but no solution yet. I was imprecise on my first post. Its a svg element that i target with element. I just tried on other blocks of my page, addClass works fine, but i can't achieve to addClass on a svg element ( a path here ) .

Comment: Well just tried on another test page with jQuery, it seems you can't addClass on svg elements at all, which seems pretty weird to me.

Comment: SVG support is only from 1.3 and forward, are you using angular 1.3?

Answer (score 25):

JqLite methods don't work with elements selected by plain javascript DOM selectors like `querySelector` or `document.getElementById()`. if you need so, first select it with javascript selectors then wrap it in `angular.element`:

```
var element = document.querySelector('a[target="_blank"]');
var angElement = angular.element(element);
```

or simply

```
var myElement = angular.element( document.querySelector('a[target="_blank"]') );
```

then you could use `JqLite` methods:
first example:

```
angElement.addClass('active');
```

second one:

```
myElement.addClass('active');
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this is generally a bad idea... Adding classes in angular is usually not done jquery style, you should use ng-class directive https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

the directive is quite simple to use..

```
<div ng-class="{active: show}"></div>
```

This div will get class active when `$scope.show` is `true`

Answer (score 2):

You have to use a directive to add and remove classes

HTML:

```
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <input type="button" active value='One' />
        <input type="button" active value='Two' />
        <input type="button" active value='Three' />
    </div>
```

JS:

```
    var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

    app.directive('active', function() {
        return {
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                element.bind('click', function() {
                    //Remove the active from all the child elements
                    element.parent().children().removeClass('active');

                    //Add active class to the clicked buttong
                    element.addClass('active');
                })
            },
        }
    });

    function MyCtrl($scope) {
    }
```

Here is the [link](http://jsfiddle.net/paila/qxkmc0ek/) to the fiddle.

Comment: This is an option but you don't _have_ to use a directive. You could accomplish the same thing in a much more generic way directly from the controller.